# Extract variables of embeded flash game

Tags: javascript, html, flash

Is it possible to extract some score variable from an html embeded game? 
Just as an example:

```
<embed src="http://www.shooter-bubble.com/bubbleshooter2.swf?pn_extravars=arcade~storescore|no_html~1" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="728" height="550">
```

Can I use any form of Js to extract any variables from this?
 My ultimate goal is to put this variable into a sql table

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the URL in the src attribute and get variables by using some kind of string analysis may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't access Flash/swf variables from HTML page that embeded it, but if you have source code of that Flash game, you can dispatch from Flash message that html page can listen. Check ExternalInterface Actionscript class:

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html